# Manage list-style size in unordered list using Font Awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

I get this code to use Font Awesome icons in an unordered list.

It works fine but I'd like to make the icons bigger and get it verticaly aligned with the text.

```
.node .field-name-body ul li { color:#333;list-style: none;}

.node .field-name-body ul li:before {    
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'; /* http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/ */
    content: '\f043';
    margin:10px 5px 0 -15px;
    color: black;
}
```

Adding **font-size** didn't worked for me

Comment: check out with `font-family: 'FontAwesome !important';`

Comment: @vas how this is going to change the size?

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/mz3gc6xx/?

Comment: @Dmitriy worked. Tested in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul{
    margin: 25px;
}
ul li { 
    color:#333;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {    
    content: '';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'; 
    content: '\f043';    
    color: black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;    
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2</li>
    <li>Link3</li>
    <li>Link4</li>
</ul>
```